# Elastic search nested document mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, mapping

I created my index and mapping, but appears that the mapping for nested documents is changed after I start adding documents to the index.

Before I start adding documents the mapping is:

```
{"products_1_1": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "metaDescription": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "metaTitle": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "mis_spells": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "productId": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "categories": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
              "default_category": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "filter_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "parent_categories_ids": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "parent_categories_names": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "parent_categories_url": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "parent_category": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "tags": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "url": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After I start inserting documents the mapping becomes:

```
{"products_1_1": {
    "mappings": {
      "product": {
        "properties": {
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "metaDescription": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "metaTitle": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "mis_spells": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "productId": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "categories": {
            "type": "nested",
            "include_in_parent": true,
            "properties": {
              "0": {
                "properties": {
                  "default_category": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "filter_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_ids": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_names": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_url": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_category": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "tags": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "url": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "1": {
                "properties": {
                  "default_category": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "filter_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_ids": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_names": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_url": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_category": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "tags": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "url": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
              "2": {
                "properties": {
                  "default_category": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "filter_name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "id": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_ids": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_names": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_categories_url": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "parent_category": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "tags": {
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  "url": {
                    "type": "string"
                  }
                }
              },
...
              "default_category": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "filter_name": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              },
              "id": {
                "type": "integer"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "parent_categories_ids": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "parent_categories_names": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "parent_categories_url": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "parent_category": {
                "type": "integer",
                "index": "no"
              },
              "tags": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "url": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "no"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Does anybody have any idea why my mapping will be altered this way?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the documents you are indexing. There is something wrong with them or with the process of creating those documents before indexing. You seem to have some kind of array whose positions are translated into numbers in the document itself.

Comment: I am running now a debug on the re-index process, checking after each indexed document if the mapping is changed.
Will post the results of that after is is finished. Thanks!